# How to remove duplicate dialing codes in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I'm trying to standardize a dataframe column of international phone numbers. I've managed to get rid of everything else except of duplicate dialing codes.

For instance, some German numbers are in the following format "00 49 49 7 123 456 789", i.e. they contain two consecutive dialing codes (49). I was wondering if there's an easy fix to get rid of the duplicate and leave the number as "00 49 7 123 456 789"

I have tried some regex and itertools.groupby solutions, however with no success, as the variations in the different dialing codes cause issues.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Can you post solution you have tried? And why its not working? May be we go somewhere from there.

Comment: Since it adds some length to the standard phone number, couldn't you just check to the length of the number and if it's too long, then it has dialing codes duplication then you remove using index because it is always at the same position

Answer (score 0):

This is a very data-driven problem, therefore the solution may change a lot depending on the actual data you are dealing with. Anyway, this will do what you want to achieve:

```
number = "00 49 49 7 123 456 789"
# Split the number to a list of number parts
num_parts = number.split()
# Define the latest position to look for a dial number
dial_code_max_pos = 4
# Iterator of tuples in the form of (number_part, next_number_part)
first_parts_with_sibling = zip(
    num_parts[:dial_code_max_pos],
    num_parts[1:dial_code_max_pos]
)
# Re-build the start of the number but removing the parts 
# that have an identical right-sibling
first_parts_with_no_duplicates = [
    num[0] for num in first_parts_with_sibling
    if len(set(num)) > 1  # This is the actual filter
]
# Compose back the number
number = ' '.join(first_parts_with_no_duplicates + num_parts[dial_code_max_pos - 1:])
```

Again, this kind of normalizations are very dangerous in production, you could end up loosing valuable data due to an algorithm that does not cover every possible kind of data.

As @Clèment said in his comment, be sure to make a few checks on the original number (i.e.: length) before applying any transformation.

Comment: thank you! It does work for the example number. However, the numbers in my dataframe don't have standardized spacing. For example, a U.S. number could be "001 123 456 7899" or "001 12345 67899". I was thinking of standardizing U.S. numbers with the regex ```"\d{2}\s\d\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d+"```, however I'm not sure how to implement it (e.g. which Regex to use)...